# Want to write a server/service for remote management, need advice

Tags: linux, mobile

I'm not sure if this belongs here, or maybe on Superuser or something. I want to write a linux based server/service that will allow me to log into my server remotely and perform a bunch of tasks, the client will be a mobile application that will need to authenticate via log-in to the server to be able to perform tasks.

I'm not sure where to begin on the server side of the work and would appreciate some information or suggestions on what sort of mechanisms I should be looking it.

I'm happy to start with something very, very basic for now that will allow me to authenticate, then give me a button to click that will show whether or not the task was carried out on the server.

Should I look at doing this with my webserver that is running on there, with some JSP or similar, or compile a native application?

If you recommend one method over another, I would like reasons why it's preferrable, which should help me choose a solution and subsequently a "correct" answer.

Thanks, and I apprecaite any help that can be offered to give me a start in the right direction.

**EDIT: I appreciate now, that I need to use a web service, so I adjust the question to ask which technology would be recommended (and preferrably a tutorial to create a web service that will execute a native command). I am familiar with Java, C, C#, C++ and will be running on a linux server, I have little/no experience with web services yet though.**

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in any number of ways. If I were to write something like this, I would probably write an API, so it can be easily implemented on the client side. It doesn't really matter what the server is, as long as it has permissions to run the tools that you need to run. The API would be an HTTP based API that would have URLs like:

```
https://server/management?userId=x&apiKey=y&command=cmd&param1=p1&param2=p2
```

This is easy both for the client and the server to implement. On the server I could have an array of supported commands, each with the supported parameters, and simply run the command if the `userId` and `apiKey` are valid and have necessary permissions. And if the `apiKey` somehow gets compromised, simply create another one for this `userId`, which will automatically invalidate the compromised `apiKey`.

Note: it's important for everything to go through HTTPS, for security reasons (you don't want anyone snooping on your `userId` and `apiKey`).

Comment: Thanks, I should have been more clear though, I will also be developing and distributing, exclusively, the client side application, so there will be no API. Does this negate the need for API keys? My only concern is the security of posting (abstract) urls with parameters like this. What's you opinion/knowledge on that?

Comment: As long as the communication goes throw SSL (HTTPS), you will be fine. Make POST requests (so they can contain as much data as needed) to an HTTPS server (so that the data cannot be snooped). As a secondary precaution, you can specify on the server that requests should only come from certain IPs, if you have static IPs.

Comment: If you're going to be the only user and also an admin user, then there is no need for user IDs or API keys. You can do the same thing, without these elements.

Comment: Thanks for the extra input, I will not necessarily be the only user, but all users will be admin, (at least in its initial iteration). Now I need to find a method of implementing... JSP, Apache, Tomcat?

Comment: Whatever you know best. If you know JSP + Tomcat, by all means, go with that. Really doesn't matter how it's implemented and on which server, as long as the user under which the server is running has access to the commands you want to issue.

Comment: My real question is whether JSP/Tomcat will give me the access/ability to run native commands or whether I'll need something different, maybe PHP5

Comment: JSP / Tomcat will give you access to run native commands. You need to run the Tomcat server as a user that has permissions to run the native commands that you need to run. Then, inside the JSP or a servlet, you can run Java's [`Runtime.exec`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29) method. What exactly do you need a tutorial on, JSP and servlets?

Comment: A good, free, online resource for learning JSP and servlets is http://pdf.moreservlets.com/.

Comment: Great, I'll get something running before I accept the answer, but I think this should certainly do, thank you.

Comment: Back again, it has been some time before I got around to looking at this, but after some time it appears now that Tomcat and JSP is not the best solution. I am still looking for an easy to implement solution that will preferably run in a standard Web server.